# Swift 2. using Parse I can't save results of a PFUser.query() in an username array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Well I'm trying to save the results of a query and when I try to save it in an array it just doesn't do it. 
Here's my code:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.orderByDescending("puntaje")
    query?.limit = 50
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (users, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = users {

            for object in objects {
                self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.scores.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    print(user.username)

                    self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                    self.scores.append((user["puntaje"] as? Int)!)
                }
            }
        }

        print(self.usernames.count)


    })
```

while printing user.username appears all the usernames.

and in the print it shows that I have 0 usernames.

Comment: When printing (self.usernames.count) whats the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move

```
self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
self.scores.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
```

above the "for" loop. Right under

```
if let objects = users {
```

Comment: Copy pasted your code and did the up mentioned modifications, got the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way.
I used:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.orderByDescending("puntaje")
    query?.limit = 50

    do {
        if let users = try query?.findObjects() {
            for user in users as! [PFUser] {
                let name = user.username!
                self.usernames.append(name)
                self.scores.append((user["puntaje"] as? Int)!)
            }
        }

    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
```